# Hyperlink in a PHP output table

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I am trying to create an output table in PHP after extracting data from a database. The fourth column needs to be a hyperlink. I have used the following code. But I am getting error in regards to the hyperlink section. Could you please let me know how to rectify it?

Thanks!

```
 echo"<tr>
            <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["age"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["sex"]."</td>                                                                                                                                                                        
            <td><a href= "https://weblink.com/path1/path2/test.php?name='.urlencode($row["name"]).'&age='.urlencode($row["age"]).'">Click for next</a></td>

  </tr>";
```

Comment: You need to escape the quotes, `\"` inside the string, the quotes that surrounds the link.

Comment: or you can use single quotes around the link

Comment: And you need to end the string with the same quote you started it with. You started with double quotes, but then ended with single quotes before `.urlencode`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your forth `<td>` your code is attempting to end the echo after `href="`, hence you have to escape the quotation mark `href=\"`. If this looks too ugly you can also use single quotes instead.

```
echo"<tr>
        <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["age"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["sex"]."</td>                                                                                                                                                                        
        <td><a href=\"https://weblink.com/path1/path2/test.php?name=".urlencode($row["name"])."&age=".urlencode($row["age"])."\">Click for next</a></td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: A good answer contains a description what was changed, not just "*try this*". What did you change, and why? Although it might be obvious to some, its better to include a description of the issue.

Comment: I agree very much. Since I was short on time and there was no answer yet I figured it would help @dash to have some working code at least. I absolutely agree with you though that a good answer should include an explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

I started php not long ago and I realized that it can be useful to format your code differently for clarity. Try using your  tags differently if you can, for exemple:

```
// end php and switch to html 
?> 

    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row["sex"]; ?></td>                                                                                                                                                                        
       <td><a href= "https://weblink.com/path1/path2/test.php?name=<?php echo urlencode($row["name"]); ?>&age=<?php echo urlencode($row["age"]); ?>">Click for next</a></td>
    </tr>

    <?php // resume php
```